# What's the purpose of this gen_server.erl code?

Tags: erlang

```erl
unregister_name({local,Name}) ->
    _ = (catch unregister(Name));
unregister_name({global,Name}) ->
    _ = global:unregister_name(Name);
unregister_name({via, Mod, Name}) ->
    _ = Mod:unregister_name(Name);
unregister_name(Pid) when is_pid(Pid) ->
    Pid.
```

This is from [gen_server.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl#L342). If `_` always matches and the match always evaluates to the right hand side expression, what are the `_ = expression()` lines doing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically `_ = ...` matches are used to quiet [dialyzer](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html) warnings about unmatched function return values when its `-Wunmatched_returns` option is used. As the documentation explains:

```
-Wunmatched_returns
    Include warnings for function calls which ignore a structured return value or
    do not match against one of many possible return value(s).
```

By explicitly matching the return value against the `_` "don't care" variable, you can use this useful dialyzer option without having to see warnings for return values you don't care about.

Answer (score 3):

In Erlang, last expression of function is its return value, so someone might be tempted to check, what `global:unregister_name/1` or `Mod:unregister_name(Name)` return and try to pattern match on that.

The `_ = expression()` doesn't do anything in particular, but hints, that this return value should be ignored (for example, because they are not documented and might be subject to change). However in the last expression, Pid is returned explicitly. This means, that you can pattern match like this:

```
case unregister_name(Something) of
    Pid when is_pid(Pid) -> foo();
    _ -> bar()
end.
```

To sum up: those lines aren't doing anything there, but when someone else is reading the source code, they show original programmer intent.

Unfortunately, this particular function is not exported and in the original module never used in pattern match, so I don't have an example to back this up :)

Comment: This sounds reasonable, also.

Answer (score 1):

And I'll note that I've since [come across this](http://pixelscommander.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/P10.pdf):

> The Power of Ten – Rules for Developing Safety Critical Code
>
> Gerard J. Holzmann
>
> NASA/JPL Laboratory for Reliable Software Pasadena, CA
>
> 91109
>
> [...]
>
> 7. Rule: The return value of non-void functions must be checked by each calling function, and the validity of parameters must be checked
>      inside each function.
>
>    Rationale: This is possibly the most frequently
>      violated rule, and therefore somewhat more suspect as a general rule.
>      In its strictest form, this rule means that even the return value of
>      printf statements and file close statements must be checked. One can
>      make a case, though, that if the response to an error would rightfully
>      be no different than the response to success, there is little point in
>      explicitly checking a return value. This is often the case with calls
>      to printf and close. In cases like these, it can be acceptable to
>      explicitly cast the function return value to (void) – thereby
>      indicating that the programmer explicitly and not accidentally decides
>      to ignore a return value. In more dubious cases, a comment should be
>      present to explain why a return value is irrelevant. In most cases,
>      though, the return value of a function should not be ignored,
>      especially if error return values must be propagated up the function
>      call chain. Standard libraries famously violate this rule with
>      potentially grave consequences. See, for instance, what happens if you
>      accidentally execute strlen(0), or strcat(s1, s2, -1) with the
>      standard C string library – it is not pretty. By keeping the general
>      rule, we make sure that exceptions must be justified, with mechanical
>      checkers flagging violations. Often, it will be easier to comply with
>      the rule than to explain why noncompliance might be acceptable.